# SQL query to finding all facts tables and bridges of a dimension table

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have a dimension table.I need to find out all the fact tables that are connected or have relation with this dimension table. is there a SQL query to find that?

Comment: Please read the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please add what database engine are you using. Answers will be completely different for each of those.

Comment: I am using Netezza DB and Aginity workbench tool

Answer (score -1):

I think you meant the child table associated with your table
for this you can use below query

```
select object_name(parent_object_id), object_name(referenced_object_id)

from sys.foreign_keys

WHERE object_name(referenced_object_id) ='TableName'
```

Comment: The question is not clear. It merits comments re clarification & downvoting & closing, not answering. Guessing in answers makes a mess. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I am using Netizza database and Aginity workbench is the query tool.